# Chrome doesn't recognize inlined sources (source map)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

Hello people of the internet,

I'm writing typescript-code and compiling it to javascript. I activated the `--inlineSourceMap` and `--inlineSources` flags. The into the javascript files embedded base64-strings looks decoded like this:

```
{
    "version":3,
    "file":"portal.service.js",
    "sourceRoot":"",
    "sources":[
        "portal.service.ts"
    ],
    "names":[

    ],
    "mappings":";;;;;;;;;;AAAA,sCA ... ,0DAAuB",
    "sourcesContent":[
        "import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; ..."
    ]
}
```

**Problem**
The sources-tab in Chrome devtools points to **portal.service.ts**, which does *NOT* exist on the server, *instead of using* the inlined sources content.

Any ideas where/what the problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the bug! We're using SystemJS Builder to bundle our application. SystemJS Builder seems to follow the map-uri's in the JS-files and therefore the map-file for the bundle points to the original ts-file instead the compiled javascript-files.